# How can I see shared friends on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, friend-list

I used to be able to see all of the Facebook friends that I have in common with another Facebook friend.  Now that Facebook changed their format, I can only seem to see shared friends with people who *aren't* my friends.

How can I see which friends I share with other Facebook friends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to your friend's page;
2. Click on the "Gear" button in the upper-right corner;
   [image]
3. Click on **See Friendship** form the drop down menu;
4. In the new page, **You and *Your Friend***, on the left column you will see the **Mutual Friends** that you have.
   [image]

Answer (score 4):

Alex is correct, but another way is to just hover over the name of your friend on one of their posts or comments and it will pop up with the number of mutual friends and pictures of up to 5 of them.  Click on the number of mutual friends to see the complete list.

Another way is to go to their profile, click on **Friends**, and then choose **Mutual Friends** from the drop-down list.